# Android facebook sdk Pagination

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

Am new to facebook sdk. I'm trying to get all of my photos through graph API. Am able to get the result with the paging field. I want to move through the previous and next. But the previous and next doesn't seems to be an url. I refere the facebook developer documentation but couldnt found any samples. Someone help me. This is my code

```
GraphRequest graphRequest = new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/"+userID+"/photos",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("Response ","Response " + response);

                    JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
                    JSONArray jarray = null;
                    try{
                        jarray = json.getJSONArray("data");
                        if(jarray != null){
                            // Loop through the "data" and get the id
                            for (int i = 0, len = jarray.length(); i < len; i++) {
                                JSONObject item = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                                noOfRequest++;
                                downloadFbPhotos(item.getString("id"));
                            }
                        }


                        if(!json.isNull("paging")) {
                            JSONObject paging = json.getJSONObject("paging");
                            JSONObject cursors = paging.getJSONObject("cursors");
                            if (!cursors.isNull("after")){
                                after = cursors.getString("after");
                            }
                            else{
                                //no after
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch(JSONException e){
                        //
                    }
                }
            }
        );

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "data,paging");
        //parameters.putString("limit", "100");
        //parameters.putString("offset", "1");
        //parameters.putString("after", "");
        graphRequest.setParameters(parameters);
        graphRequest.executeAsync();
```

This is a sample response:

> 09-02 15:31:11.794: D/Response(1523): Response {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"data":[{"id":"785636858147560"},{"id":"653561304732935"},{"id":"10152196967129315"},{"id":"504111853031524"},{"id":"724361997575090"},{"id":"10201722174609862"},{"id":"553468811388609"}],"paging":{"cursors":{"after":"TlRVek5EWTRPREV4TXpnNE5qQTVPakV6TnprMk5USTJOVFE2TXprME1EZAzVOalF3TmpRM09ETTIZD","before":"TnpnMU5qTTJPRFU0TVRRM05UWXdPakUwTURVNU1qRXlORGM2TXprME1EZAzVOalF3TmpRM09ETTIZD"}}}, error: null}

The sample response response doesn't contains previous and next. Instead it contains only before and after. So, How do I use the paging in this code. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are right. It's not url. To access paginate data you should attach before/after={the thing you get in result} to your request